# Send request to WebAPI as service account

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have two applications.

- Both on the same server
- Both running as the same service account
- Both require windows Auth

I'm trying to use HttpClient to get from one app to the other with a simple post request; however, the identity doesn't seem to get used.

What I'm using looks like this:

```
var testIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{ 
    //...
    HttpResponseMessage respose = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/controller/Method", request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Exception here!
    //...
}
```

I've verified `testIdentity` is the service account I want to be running as, but it doesn't seem to make it. I always get a 401 response back.

I've also tested the application sending the request locally (but same domain), and the WebAPI on the server, but that doesn't work either (same 401 response).

If I have both applications local then it works as expected.

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: I have seen problem with the way SPN is setup in this kind of use cases, check the below link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928350/how-can-i-fix-the-kerberos-double-hop-issue

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking there might be this issue, but does it really still apply if its the same domain user for both applications?

Comment: this happens when you have to pass windows credentials from one server to another, nothing to do with same domain i believe.

Comment: Gotcha, I was thinking that it happened when moving between physical machines for some reason

Comment: Okay, so this isn't the issue I'm having. The first server is the client, and it's going to the WebAPI (as the server's app pool user). I'm not actually making two hops.

Comment: Ok check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430045/how-to-pass-windows-authentication-credential-from-client-to-web-api-service

Comment: So, I figured out that `await response.Content.ReadStringAsAsync()` gave a lot more detailed information regarding the error. I'm actually getting a Logon Method of Negotiate, and the Logon User of the account I expect. That said, I'm getting a `401.2 Unauthorized` error.

Comment: @Prashant, if you have any insight as to why the answer I posted fixed the problem for me that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little hesitant to accept this as the answer as I don't know the underlying cause yet; however, the issue I ran into was fixed by impersonating an account on a different domain.