# How to use Asp.Net Web Api with window authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a application on local network with window authentication. Application is working fine. There is a old version of application too that is running on the same network. New application will replace old one later on. But for time being i need service to be exposed for old application. What i did is i made an API in the same application where window authentication is being used. Now the problem is that i don't want any kind of authentication on Web API but i am unable to test it by any tool like postman and fiddler. When i hit the URI it shows 401 error. Even i have to give windows credentials in browser to test it. After window authentication in browser service is running fine but i want to without window authentication.

I have tried many things like i put [allowanonymous] attribute on controller level. I put location tag with anonymous users in web.config file but nothing is working for me.

Can anyone tell me is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: what is window authentication?!? do you mean *Windows*?

Comment: Does this question cover what you're asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430045/how-to-pass-windows-authentication-credential-from-client-to-web-api-service

Comment: @user1859022 yes it is windows.